# How can I run multiple unique WordPress sites off of one VPS

Tags: multisite, urls

Is it possible to run multiple WordPress sites off of a single VPS?  These sites would be completely separate as far as users and content, but I don't know if it's possible to have this for two different URLs.

Looking at the [Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) documentation, it appears that is used for different sub-domains, but I want to be able to run **example.com** and **test.com** as two separate sites but hosted on the same server.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have two options, you can either do vhosting and have separate instances for each domain. This would mean the sites would be completely independent from each other. If you're thinking of selling of a site or moving it to a different vps/server because it's outgrown the current and deserving of it's own server. Also some plugins don't fully support multisites. Drawbacks are this is a high maintance and harder task to do.

Or you can turn your site into a multi site install and then use the Domain Mapping Plugin Pippin has mentioned. This is all round the easier method, you just follow the instructions. And you're users can use the same account on both sites. Depending on your setup multisites can result in a major pain in the ass. However for most people it's just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by separate instances? I want to have one server so I'm not paying hosting for each site as they will be quite small. Can I set them up separately on one server so they are independent and I only have to pay for the one server?

Comment: Yea instances just means seperate WordPress installs. Depending on your set up, if you've got a cpanel/plesk set up you can create a new vhost via the web ui. However if you're doing it by hand then you'll most likely being using Apache with the documention for that being found at http://iain.at/6 you could also create new database and username and password but an easier option would be to use the same mysql details and then just change the database prefix in wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Domain Mapping Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) is what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want physically separate installs, then... yes. You do not need the network feature for that.

I have multiple domains on one vps, some single WP installs, some networks, some with domain mapping, some not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the easiest and less troublesome way of having multiple sites on one hosting account simply set up separate Wordpress installs using the one database, just change the table prefixes so you don't override a pre-existing Wordpress installation.

Wordpress multisites DO work, but they can be an absolute pain to get working right with multiple domains. Of course after you have installed your separate installations of Wordpress, you'll then need to map each domain to its respective separate copy of Wordpress.